# ngDialog modal does not pop up

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-dialog

I am trying to display a simple modal on click of a button. The modal does not pop up. It displays the contents on the same existing window.(snapshot attached)

My Code is below:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="Pcp">
<head>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="ng-dialog/js/ngDialog.min.js"></script>
    <script src="ng-dialog/js/ngDialog.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="MainController">
    <button ng-click="openTaskForm()">Open</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('Pcp',['ngDialog']);
     app.controller('MainController', function($scope, ngDialog)
    {
        $scope.openTaskForm = function(){
        ngDialog.open({template: 'addTaskForm.html'

        });

        };      
    }
);

})();
```

addTaskForm.html

```
<div>
    <h2>Contact us<h2>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" ng-model="name" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" ng-model="email" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Mobile" ng-model="mobile" />
    <textarea placeholder="Enter your message or query..." ng-model="message"></textarea>
    <div class="ngdialog-buttons">
        <button type="button" class="ngdialog-button ngdialog-button-secondary" ng-click=closeThisDialog("Cancel")>Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="ngdialog-button ngdialog-button-primary" ng-click=confirm("OK")>OK</button>
        </div>
</div>
```

Please let me know why modal is not working.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSVtQ.png)

Comment: Firstly include either ngDialog.min.js or ngDialog.js (as both are same). Also include it before app.js. And what is the error that you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

You should include css files of ngDialog in header:

```
<head>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="ng-dialog/js/ngDialog.min.js"></script>
    <script src="ng-dialog/js/ngDialog.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/ngDialog.css}" href="../../css/ngDialog.css" > </link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/ngDialog-theme-default.css}" href="../../css/ngDialog-theme-default.css" > </link>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ngDialog.open({
       template: 'addTaskForm.html',
       scope : $scope,
       resolve: {
           data: function sendData() {
               return data; // if you need to pass any data
           }
       }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Does not work. It still shows the old behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem and implemented above suggestions by @Enigo and @Sujata but didn't help. Upon analysing further I noticed my mistake of rendering CSS files as `media="print"` so corrected them to `media="screen"` See below:

```
<link href='@Styles.Url("~/lib/Dialog/ngDialog-theme-default.css")' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link href='@Styles.Url("~/lib/Dialog/ngDialog-theme-plain.css")' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

Hope this helps. Please note `@Styles.Url()` is ASP.NET MVC Razor syntax.